# Perl & Imagemagick - cannot find lperl

Tags: perl, imagemagick

I've got a custom compiled perl, and trying to get ImageMagick working in it.

Whenever I try and compile imagemagick I get

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lperl
```

I assume its trying to find libperl.

```
locate libperl
```

shows its in

```
/opt/perl/lib/5.14.2/x86_64-linux/CORE/libperl.a
/opt/perl/lib/5.14.2/x86_64-linux/CORE/libperl.so
/usr/lib/libperl.so.5.18
/usr/lib/libperl.so.5.18.2
```

When compiling, I've tried

```
./configure --with-perl=/opt/perl/bin/perl
```

I've also tried options

```
--enable-shared --with-perl-options=LIBPERL_A=libperl.a --with-perl-options=LIBS=/opt/perl/lib/5.14.2/x86_64-linux/CORE
```

and also compiling perl with and without -Duseshrplib to create the .so file.

Can anyone explain why it can't find perl and how to compile it ?

edit: one thing that lets it compile is ln -s /usr/lib/libperl.so.5.18 /usr/lib/libperl.so but surely that means its looking at the wrong perl install ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I needed to set LDFLAGS

LDFLAGS=-L/opt/perl/lib/5.14.2/x86_64-linux/CORE ./configure...